# Sorting a list by int values in a String

Tags: python

I have a List e.g.:

```
Name - Seconds: 3.14 - Mistakes: 0
DsO - Seconds: 7.09 - Mistakes: 0
Xardas - Seconds: 7.24 - Mistakes: 0
Badudu1 - Seconds: 13.55 - Mistakes: 1
```

How can I sort it by seconds?

So the user types in his name which is the first entry before the " - "

I tried it with this:

```
seconds_position = len(user_input) + len(" - Seconds: ")
seconds = substring[seconds_position]
seconds = seconds.partition(" ")[0]
```

I guess that I could just do this for every list entry and compare them but how do I compare it when the seconds are two-digit before the comma?

Answer (score 2):

Use `re` module with `.sort` or `sorted`:

```py
import re

new_list = sorted(original_list, key=lambda x: float(re.search('Seconds:\s(\d+\.\d+)', x).group(1)))
```

To do it inplace use:

```py
original_list.sort(key=lambda x: float(re.search('Seconds:\s(\d+\.\d+)', x).group(1)))
```

### Edit:

if you don't want to use a library change the `key` to:

```py
key = lambda x: float(x.split('-')[1][10:-1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to import something. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a key to sorted function and that key can be a lambda function.
change `lst` with the name of your list. This takes the float part of the list item.

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: float(x.split('-')[1][len(' Seconds: '):]))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use timedelta you can then make arithmetic operations on your seconds

```
a="""Name - Seconds: 3.14 - Mistakes: 0
DsO - Seconds: 7.09 - Mistakes: 0
Xardas - Seconds: 7.24 - Mistakes: 0
Badudu1 - Seconds: 13.55 - Mistakes: 1"""
from datetime import timedelta
deltas=[]
for line in a.splitlines():
    seconds=line.split(' - ')[1].split(':')[1].strip()
    deltas.append(timedelta(seconds=float(seconds)))
print(deltas[0]+2*deltas[1])
>>> 0:00:17.320000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the key parameter of the sort method to extract the numeric value of seconds in each string:

Depending on the patterns that are possible in your strings, this extraction could be as simple as a split or it may require more sophisticated parsing (using a regular expression for example).

Here is an example with a simple split:

```
L = ["Name - Seconds: 3.14 - Mistakes: 0",
     "Badudu1 - Seconds: 13.55 - Mistakes: 1",
     "DsO - Seconds: 7.09 - Mistakes: 0",
     "Xardas - Seconds: 7.24 - Mistakes: 0",
]

L.sort(key=lambda i:float(i.split()[3]))

print(L)
['Name - Seconds: 3.14 - Mistakes: 0', 
 'DsO - Seconds: 7.09 - Mistakes: 0', 
 'Xardas - Seconds: 7.24 - Mistakes: 0', 
 'Badudu1 - Seconds: 13.55 - Mistakes: 1']
```